# Android studio incorrect duplicate class error due to directory junctions?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Is there any way to make android studio stop giving incorrect duplicate class errors ?

Let's say I have A.java that lies inside com.bla.bla.appname (com/bla/bla/appname/A.java).

I created an android studio project that doesn't contain this hierarchy but contains a directory junction inside. So I have this app/main/src/**(this is the junction)com** => com/bla/bla/appname/A.java).

So the project actually builds just fine (despite of intellisense duplicate class errors), because the A.java file has the correct package hierarchy, but android studio seems simply stupid and not capable of seeing that there is actually no problem at all.

I just want to get rid of that red underlined error, because it highlights my entire root folder as containing errors (fake errors). I can't seem to find any way to supress the duplicate class error or telling android studio that there is no duplicate class.

Anyone has any clues ?

Comment: If you mean [Windows directory junctions](https://superuser.com/questions/343074/directory-junction-vs-directory-symbolic-link), that may not be scenario that the developers considered. You might consider filing a feature request for better support for this.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean... or at least I would want a way to disable the errors on the user interface side. I will fill a feature request I guess.

Comment: this problem also occurs if you have the same class in two directories within the project, but one directory is not in the java src files list. Compiler understands that only one of the class paths is active but the code hinting does not.